# Not able to fetch post with relationship field type Advance custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

> Hi i have a post type Games and Games Docs. In Games Docs i have a field Game filter(game_filter) where i have games taxonomies in drop down where only one option can be chosen. Now i want to do is when i'm in single-games.php i want to show the content of the game-docs post with the game_filter field. [This link where Plugin has shown how to accomplish this but not useful in my case](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/)
>
> tried this code but not working

```
$inerargs = array(
                'post_type' => 'game-docs', 
                'meta_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                    'key' => 'game_filter', // name of custom field
                                    'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', 
                                    'compare' => '='
                                )
                            )
                        );
```

> added the screen shots. kindly check [image: Advance custom field section]

[image: game-docs post type section]